# django forms, not valid

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-validation

so no matter what I seem to do I can't get a valid form from just a integer field.

Controller:

```
def upload_image(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        form = AddFloorplan(request.POST, request.FILES)

        print request.POST.get('floornumber')


        if form.is_valid():
            print 'valid'
        else:
            print(form.errors)

        return redirect("/wayfinder/editor/")
```

Form:

```
class AddFloorplan(forms.Form):
    floor_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
```

Template:

```
            <form action="/wayfinder/addfloorplan/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="floornumber" autofocus name="floornumber" placeholder="Floor Number" type="text" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col s12">
                    <p>
                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light z-depth-0" type="submit" name="action">
                            <span>Upload</span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </form>
```

had no luck passing the values

Comment: what is the form.errors you are receiving because in case your `form.is_valid()` is returning `False` you should be getting form.errors.

Comment: I can't help noticing that the name of the field in your template `floornumber` is different from the name of the field in your form `floor_number` ...

Comment: It says that the Field is required and empty, but when I get the details via a request.POST it prints out fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your form field, `floor_number`

```
floor_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
```

does not match the name of your form input, `floornumber`

```
<input id="floornumber" autofocus name="floornumber" placeholder="Floor Number" type="text" required>
```

You need to use the same name in both places.

Comment: That was the issue thanks, now a forms.ModelChoiceField that I populate from the database refuses to work by saying am picking an invalid selection. The names are the same.

Comment: That's not enough info. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Ah dont worry about it, I'll just keep hacking at it